# MongoDb aggregate query three collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am really new to MongoDB query and practicing mongoDb query. I am using this official [mongoDb-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb). I am following this [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) .I have three collections of data. One is bags, one is sellers and last one is cloths. Our data architecture is When seller sends bags of cloths with his/her informations. We created seller collections like this:

```
{   "sellerId": 1234,
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "doe",
    "fullName": "John Doe",
    "email": "john@yahoo.com",
    "bagId": 2224
}
```

**this is bag collection**

```
 { 
   "sellerId": 1234
    "bagId": 2224,
    "source" : "fedex"
}
```

After selection the cloths from bags which is suppose to be sell, we create cloth collection.

```
[
{
    "bagId": 2224,
    "brandName": "Denim",
    "size": "32",
    "clothId": 1244,
    "color": "green",
    "price": 20
},
{
    "bagId": 2224,
    "brandName": "Zara",
    "size": "31",
    "clothId": 1243,
    "color": "red",
    "price": 90
}
]
```

When the cloth get sold from Shopify. we get arrays of **SKU-ID** which is our cloth collections clothId.

**My goal is when the cloth get sold, we match the clothId(SKU-ID FROM SHOPIFY) the find bagId, from that bagId we will get the seller information.**

**My expected outcome is**

{

```
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "doe",
    "fullName": "John Doe",
    "email": "john@yahoo.com",
    "bagId": 2224,
    "clothId": 1244 // sold cloth id which I got from Shopify
    "sellerId": 1234
}
```

I successfully match the sold cloth id and shopify (SKU-ID) and get bags info but I could not able figure it out, how to get get sellers info from the bagId

**This is what my code where I get sold-cloth info and bags details but it does not give me seller's info just got empty arrays**

```
const sllerInfo = await client
    .db()
    .collection('clothes')
    .aggregate(
      [
        { $match: { clothId: { '$in': convertInto } } }, // convertInto is arrays of sold clothId which I got from Shopify
        {
          $lookup:
          {
            from: "bags",
            localField: "bagId",
            foreignField: "bagId",
            as: "bags"
          }
        },
        {
          $lookup:
          {
            from: "sellers",
            localField: "sellerId",
            foreignField: "sellerId",
            as: "sellers"
          },
        },
        {
          "$project": {
            "bagId": 1.0,
            "bags.source": 1.0,
            "sellers.firstName": 1.0, // dont get anything
            "sellers.lastName": 1.0,  // dont get anything
            "brand": 1.0
          }
        },
      ]
    ).toArray()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/MjGG_8HLT1T

You have to use [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/), you need to get seller id from `bags.sellerId`

```
db.clothes.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      clothId: {
        "$in": [
          1244,
          1243
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "bags",
      localField: "bagId",
      foreignField: "bagId",
      as: "bags"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$bags" // break into individual documents
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "sellers",
      localField: "bags.sellerId", // you need to get seller id from bags
      foreignField: "sellerId",
      as: "sellers"
    },
    
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$sellers"  // break into individual documents
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: 0,
      "clothId": 1,
      "sellerId": "$sellers.sellerId",
      "bagId": 1,
      "bags.source": 1,
      "sellers.firstName": 1,
      "sellers.lastName": 1,
      "brand": 1
    }
  }
])
```

---

You can skip unwinding in case you know there will be the only matching element coming from lookup.

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/IP0epMpQ6mE